# Recursively zip files into .cbz-files based on folder in command line

Tags: macos, bash, automation, zip, terminal.app

I'm trying to figure out how to write a script to automate creating .cbz files from images in folders on OSX.

My directory tree will look like this:

```
/toplevel/
cbz/
comics/
    Comic1/
        comic1file1.jpg
        comic1file2.gif
        comic1file3.png
    Comic2/
        comic2file1.jpg
        comic2file2.gif
    Publisher/
            Comic3/
                comic3file1.jpg
                comic3file2.gif
                comic3file3.png
            Comic4/
                comic4file1.jpg
                comic4file2.gif
```

And what I'd like to do is run a script that will find any folder containing actual files rather than subfolders and zip it, rename it from .zip to .cbz and move the .cbz file to the /cbz folder on the toplevel. Any folder that contains subfolders should not contain any files, so that might be helpful. Also I don't expect there to ever be subfolders deeper than what is shown in the example above.

Where I'm at: This snippet will look through a folder and create the .cbz-files for each subfolder.

```
for dir in `ls`; do zip $dir $dir/*; mv $dir*zip $dir.cbz; done
```

I've also found some snippets that will do something similar to every subfolder below the selected folder, but I've had varying results and would be very interested to learn the best way of performing an operation only on folders. Also I have NO clue as to how I should check whether a given folder contains subfolders or files. (I guess ideally I should include checks to see if there are both, but for my current scenario that shouldn't ever be the case.)
Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to SU! We're not a script writing service.  What have you got so far? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: I'm sorry if that's how I came across. I have managed to put together this snippet that will do the job for a single level of folders: ´for dir in `ls`; do zip $dir $dir/*; mv $dir*zip $dir.cbz; done´ and I've managed to make it look for subfolders. My biggest hurdle right now is determining if a folder contains subfolders or files.

Comment: No worries. Please edit your question and include what you've got so far, and describe where/how you're getting stuck modifying it to do what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another slightly different solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
find toplevel/comics -type d -not -empty -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' dir; do
  if find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f | read f; then
    zip toplevel/cbz/"$(basename "$dir").cbz" "$dir"/*
  fi
done
```

- `find … -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file` is [a recommended pattern](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) to iterate over `find` results. Doing a simple `find … | while read file` works fine, but only if the returned file names do not contain a newline. Parsing `ls` is never recommended.
- `find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f | read f` only evaluates true if files are found in the directory. It achieves the same purpose of @terdon's evaluation of the number of lines output by `find`.
- Quotes are needed around all variables in order to prevent whitespace in the file names from breaking the arguments.

Comment: Nice, clever to use `read` that way.

Comment: This seems to work beautifully! I'll accept the answer as soon as the script is done and I can check one of the archives. :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, [never parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Also, you can give `zip` an arbitrary name for the archive it will create so you don't need to move the files. Try this:

```
find toplevel/comics/ -mindepth 1 -type d | 
while read dir; do 
    num=$(find "$dir" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l )  
    [ "$num" -gt "0" ] && zip toplevel/cbz/"$(basename $dir)".cbd "$dir"/*; 
done
```

The 1st `find` command searches `toplevel/comics/` for directories (`type -d`) that are at least one level below (`-mindepth 1`) the path given (subdirectories). This ensures that `find` will not return `toplevel/comics` itself as a result. 
The results of that find are piped to the `while` loop which processes each of them saved in the variable `$dir`. Each `$dir` is searched for files (`-type f`) that are actually in that directory and not in sub directories (`-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1`). The number of lines returned by the `find` (that's what `wc` does) is saved as `$num` and if it is greater than 0, the directory is zipped and the archive placed into `cbz`.

NOTES: The archives will contain the full path to the files (test by unpacking one), you might want to give the `-j` option to `zip` if you don't want this. See [`man zip`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/zip.1.html).

Comment: Beat me to it. You might want to double-quote `toplevel/cbz/$(basename "$dir").cbd` in case the base name is expanded with whitespace. For really paranoid file handling, it should be `find … -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' dir; do …`.

Comment: @slhck good point about the `$(basename "$dir")`, answer edited. I didn't include the IFS etc to keep things simple since the OP is just starting with shell scripting and since you have it in your version anyway.

Comment: This is looking very promising, but something still snags. Making some adjustments to reflect the actual file structure I ended up with saving this as "cbzmaker.sh" in what would be the "toplevel" dir:



`#! /bin/bash
find Comics -mindepth 1 -type d | 
while read dir; do 
    num=$(find "$dir" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l )  
    [ "$num" -gt "0" ] && zip CBZs/"$(basename $dir)".cbz "$dir"; 
done`



This seems to find all folders and create zips based on their names, but they all seem to be empty.

Comment: @Martin sorry, my bad, try with the updated version.